# Issue with MySQL query to update users based on last visit timestamp

Tags: mysql

I'm encountering an issue with a MySQL query aimed to update user records in my table based on their last visit timestamp. I want to update the enabled column to 0 for users who haven't visited in the past before 2018.

Here's the query I've tried:

```
UPDATE mantis_user_table
SET enabled = 0
WHERE last_visit < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 YEAR);
```

However, this query doesn't seem to work as expected, and it's  updating everything.
I've verified that the last_visit column contains valid timestamp data.

Can anyone spot what might be wrong with my query or suggest an alternative approach to achieve the desired result?

Thank you.

Comment: What is the datatype of the `last_visit` column?

Comment: this is an example from my DB : '1669200237'

Comment: The Datatype is INT(10)

Comment: Well that is your problem, if you are storing the date as an INT similar to UNIX TIME STAMP format, its not in DATE format.   UPDATE - Bill explained more about it below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your value `1669200237` looks like a UNIX timestamp, that is a 32-bit integer.

```
mysql> select from_unixtime(1669200237);
+---------------------------+
| from_unixtime(1669200237) |
+---------------------------+
| 2022-11-23 02:43:57       |
+---------------------------+
```

You can't compare that to a MySQL datetime value, without converting the datetime to a similar integer with the [UNIX_TIMESTAMP() function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp).

```
UPDATE mantis_user_table
SET enabled = 0
WHERE last_visit < UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 YEAR));
```

Keep in mind that using 32-bit integers as timestamps is going to become a problem by 2038, which is not that many years from now.

Comment: I often wonder about tthis .. do you speculate that there will be a 64 bit upgrade by the time that date rolls around so we just fix it then with the larger value? Or is that a pipedream and we should do the multiple lines of code formatting the dates to perpare for it a few years earlier?

Comment: @easleyfixed, Most operating systems and databases already offer a solution. But in the case of MySQL, their solution is the `DATETIME` data type. The legacy `TIMESTAMP` data type will remain a 32-bit value, so it will never support dates past the end of that range. If a given application is designed to store timestamps as 32-bit integers, that will also end 14 years from now.

Comment: Yes, but if the issue is that the 32 digit value runs out of numbers, is it possible in a theoretical MySQL 12 update in the future, they add 64 digit support so that we can just change the datatypes to support the larger value, and thus continue to function without updates to front ends or other reliances?

Comment: @easleyfixed, Also consider that some applications work with dates in the future, even more than 14 years in the future. Mortgage calculators, for example. So they have to solve this problem already.

Comment: I mean yes, but similar to the Y2K problem of yore, when we ran out of 2 digits and wanted to support 4, is it not fessible to assume MySQL wants to remain relevant and support dates beyond its limited design for the much more efficient integer values versus actual mysql date formats?

Comment: @easleyfixed, MySQL already offers a `DATETIME` data type that supports a larger range of dates.

Comment: I know and its horribly backwards for readability sake, and I know you can format it, but its a bane.   Im just inquring if you think they will ever upgrade the UNIX_TIMESTAMP command to support 64 bit values, it seems feesible, perhaps I need ot ask them and not ask for speculation, but I would like to hope thats the case someday.

Comment: @easleyfixed, Read the documentation for `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` I linked to. It does support 64-bit timestamp values in MySQL 8.0.28 and later, if running on an operating system that supports such values. But you can't store that value in a legacy MySQL `TIMESTAMP` column.

Comment: I guess that is the question I'm asking, you think they will every upgrade the backend?

Comment: @easleyfixed, They wrote in the [MySQL 8.0.28 release notes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/8.0/en/news-8-0-28.html): _"The behavior of the TIMESTAMP type is also unaffected by this change; its maximum allowed value remains '2038-01-19 03:14:07.999999' UTC, regardless of platform. For dates futureward of this, use the MySQL DATETIME type instead."_

Comment: So sounds like as of that patch there is no documented plans to update the feature into a newer format the supports legacy and future values.   Thanks for the citation.

Comment: I think it would overcomplicate the MySQL code to make `TIMESTAMP` have multiple internal formats. And this complexity is hard to justify, given that they already have another temporal data type that solves the same need.